# Why does function setValues do not change values of NSManaged object of type Phone?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I created structure PhoneStructure. It should contain values from NSManaged object of CoreData entity Phone.
It has two function:
Function that gets values from Phone to save them in PhoneStructure(getValues) and function that gets value PhoneStructure to save them in Phone(setValues). However set function doesn't change values of Phone:

```
struct GenderStructure: Setable {
var status: String?

func setValues<T: NSManagedObject>(of object: T){
    guard let gender = object as? Gender else { return }

    gender.setValue(status, forKey: "status")
}
mutating func getValues<T: NSManagedObject>(from object: T){
    guard let gender = object as? Gender else { return }
    self.status = gender.status
}
```

At the same time, somehow setValues function of LocationStructure works although it is the same function, but which works with different entity(Location)

```
struct LocationStructure: Named{
var name: String?
var longitude: Double
var latitude: Double
init() {
    name = nil
    longitude = 0
    latitude = 0
}

init(name: String, longitude: Double, latitude: Double){
    self.name = name
    self.longitude = longitude
    self.latitude = latitude
}
func setValues<T: NSManagedObject>(of object: T){

    guard let location = object as? Location else { return }

    location.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    location.setValue(longitude, forKey: "longitude")
    location.setValue(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
}
mutating func getValues<T: NSManagedObject>(from object: T){

    guard let location = object as? Location else { return }

    self.name = location.name
    self.longitude = location.longitude
    self.latitude = location.latitude
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but why do you use functions with a generic parameter but actually it considers only one type respectively? That's not the purpose of generics.

Comment: Protocol Setable requires generic func setValue and getValue. As a result I can use different types of objects(Phone, Location) in one generic function with generic  <Structure: Setable>.

Comment: A protocol with generic type which requires a type check at runtime is pretty inefficient and makes no sense.

Comment: Phone, Gender? Which one is it, did you post the right code? And I agree that your use of generics doesn’t make much sense here.